# Align a figure's border with that of the text's body

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

In the example below I want `image-example-b`'s right border to at or to the right of the body of text's border. As it is there is a gap. I wasn't expecting this as the `textwidth` spanned by the two `minipage`'s is 1.0, and the figure inside the RHS is within a `flushright` environnment. If I change `textwidth` to `paperwidth` it then crosses that border and creates a trailing page. I could fine tune the width, but that is not satisfactory as it depends on the documents layout.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
% last:
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage 
% Here starts backcover% <======================================================
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\pagecolor{blue}
{
  \Large

  \color{red}

  \textbf{\lipsum[2]}

  \begin{center}
  \keyfig[H]{lw=0.6}{example-image-a}
  \end{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   Who I Am
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
%    \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{flushright}
  \keyfig[H]{lw=0.4,cstar{}}{example-image-b}
    \end{flushright}
%    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}

}
% Here ends backcover


\end{document}
```

[image: Print]

Comment: apparently `\keyfig` is  forcing centering in the surrounding box so your flushright environment is having no effect and it is centred in the right hand box (note you have a word space between the two `.5\textwidth boxes` due to missing `%` after the first.)

Comment: I think wrapping the two horizontal items in `keysubfigs`, getting proper alignment within, horiz/vert, what I'm looking into.

Comment: I'd not seen the package before so can't really help (too late to read package doc this evening:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% last:
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
% Here starts backcover% <======================================================
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{blue}
{
  \Large

  \color{red}

  \textbf{\lipsum[2]}
%
 \begin{center}
 \keyfig[H]{lw=0.6}{example-image-a}
 \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.3\textwidth}@{}}
 Who I Am &
 \keyfig[H]{w=\hsize, cstar={}}{example-image-b}
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{center}

% Here ends backcover

\end{document}
```

[image]