# How to link to back cover?

Tags: hyperref

This is a follow up to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508997/align-a-figures-border-with-that-of-the-texts-body/509008#509008). I'd like to refer to the backcover. What I tried failed:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{keyfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% last:
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum[1]

% HERE LIES PROBLEM <-----

Also see \hyperref[backcover]{backcover}. %links to page 1 (wrong)

\autopageref{backcover} %links to page 1 (wrong), prints page 2.

% ------------------------>

\clearpage
% Here starts backcover% <======================================================
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\afterpage{\label{backcover}} %afterpage disables the label
\label{backcover}
\pagecolor{blue}
{
  \Large

  \color{red}

  \textbf{\lipsum[2]}
%
 \begin{center}
 \keyfig[H]{lw=0.6}{example-image-a}
 \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.3\textwidth}@{}}
 Who I Am &
 \keyfig[H]{w=\hsize, cstar={}}{example-image-b}
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{center}

% Here ends backcover

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an anchor for the link. In many cases (if counters are involved) hyperref does it automatically. But sometimes you need an explicit `\phantomsection`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum[1]

Also see \hyperref[backcover]{backcover}. 
\autopageref{backcover}

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\label{backcover}
backcover

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've used it before, blindspot, for some reason. Thank you.